# Size type string

Tags: c#

```
string s1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf2);
```

I see type string only limit 8 bytes(8 character). everybody can tell me how way to receive more than 8 bytes?
Detail:

server

```
        byte[]  buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileSize.ToString());
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();    
        ms.Write(buf,0,buf.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] buf2 = new byte[32*1024];
        ms.Read(buf2,0,buf2.Length);
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(savefilename);
        MessageBox.Show("1 " + buf2.Length +" "+ fileSize+" "+ms.Length);
        int ns = sendSocket.Send(buf2, sizeof(ulong), SocketFlags.None);
```

client

```
            byte[] buf = new byte[32 * 1024];
            int nr = listenSocket2.Receive(buf, sizeof(ulong), SocketFlags.None);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte[] buf2 = new byte[32 * 1024];
            ms.Read(buf2, 0, buf2.Length);

            string s1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf2);
            MessageBox.Show("" + s1+" "+ms.Length);
            ulong fileSize = UInt64.Parse(s1);
```

s1 is not more than 8 character

Comment: The string data type can hold any (reasonable) number of characters you need. Did you try using a bigger buffer?

Comment: What is in buf2?  Are you sure it is valid ASCII data?

Comment: @p.s.w.g + shf301 . I use buf 32KB :(. this line code I use in app send file. this is it: [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?qqbphpr3r2zbl92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line

```
int nr = listenSocket2.Receive(buf, sizeof(ulong), SocketFlags.None);
```

Reads the first 8 bytes from the stream. This is meant to contain the *size* of the file. You should issue another `Receive` to receive the actual file contents.

Comment: do you way other? I declared receive **sizeof(ulong)** :(

Comment: Yes, you indicated that you wanted to receive 8 bytes, and that's what you got. Those 8 bytes contain the length of the rest of the message. Your example doesn't show you actually send the file contents.